# Angular 4 with universal

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

I am using angular 2 with a universal.

I am trying to this.

First I create a new project :

```
ng new universaldemo.
```

I installed these packages :

```
npm install --save @angular/platform-server @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader ts-loader @nguniversal/express-engine.
```

Here is my app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'universaldemo' }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my app.server.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule
  ],
  providers: [
    // Add universal-only providers here
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

Here is my server.ts :

// These are important and needed before anything else

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// TODO: implement data requests securely
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
});

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
Here is my webpack.server.config.js :

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: { server: './server.ts' },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
  target: 'node',
  // this makes sure we include node_modules and other 3rd party libraries
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }]
  },
  plugins: [
    // Temporary Fix for issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
    // for 'WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression'
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

Finally i create tsconfig.server.json :

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

Below lines are added to my package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build:universal": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:universal": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
    ...
}
```

I try to create build and serve my app :

```
npm run build:universal
```

It works.

I try to run my app.using this command

```
npm run serve:universal.
```

I got this error.

> ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined at Object

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `webpack.server.config.js` file as described in the Universal Wiki : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering

Do you Angular 5 or the older 2/4 version? Maybe your package.json is outdated?!

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I have one doubt.i build my app.Dist folder contains browser and server folder and server.js.Which folder uploaded to my server.

Comment: you have to upload following files:

- package.json
- dist/
-- browser/
-- server/
-- preiender.js
-- server.js

then on the server run `npm install` to install dependencies for the application (or upload the node_module folder as well).

then, from the main folder as well run `npm run serve:ssr` or `node dist/server`

// EDIT: in your case you should use `npm run serve:universal`

Comment: hi.Denis.I post new question Can u help me.Pls refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47150583/angular-with-universal-getting-error