# Angular universal : Splitting project [solution for old or complex project]

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I work on a pretty old angular project, we started working on it on 2.0 release, and upgraded it  release after release. We're on 4.3 for now

Now, the project is very complex, with a lot of features, and a lot of (old) peer dependencies, not maintained anymore for some of them.

I tried to implement angular universal on this project, to improve SEO, but I come accross errors one after another, and it looks like there's no end at this.

So my questions are :

- is there a way to implement angular universal on old project, without refactoring everything ?
- if no, is there a way to implement angular universal only on a part of the project, like on statical-non-complex pages ?

All answer and hints are welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing Angular universal on old project can be really, really painful :

- You use vanilla javascript => it can't compile
- You use a peer dep that uses vanilla javascript => it can't compile, and there is a lot of old deps coded this way

I have to implement it on a old project too, and, like you, I had a lot of compilation errors. So I decided to split my app between two parts, two projects :

- The angular *old-dependent* part, with complex code/feature
- The static pages that needs to be SEO friendly => and, good news, this is what brings you the most *SEO juice*

The bad part is that the 2 projects are independent from each others, so you can't use things like `localStorage`, `routerLink` etc. But they're connected to the same API, so you can always share data between them

Technically, I did it like this :

1. Creating a new `app-universal` folder, with the `app-universal.module.ts`
2. Importing what I needed from the initial project (like some helpers/interface/services)
3. Building my statics pages, with SEO friendly content
4. Implementing Angular universal on the project, thanks to this guide : [Angular Universal guide](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-)
5. Changing the `<base href="">` of the simplified app to `<base href="/content">`
6. Creating 3 projects in my `angular-cli.json`:

---

```
 "apps": [
{
  "name": "app",
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "app/main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  ...
},
{
  "name": "universal",
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist-universal",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "app-universal/index.html",
  "main": "app-universal/main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app-universal",
  "...
},
{
  "name": "server",
  "platform": "server",
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "src/app-universal/dist-universal-server",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "app-universal/index.html",
  "main": "app-universal/main.server.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "app-universal/tsconfig.server.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app-universal",
  ...
}
],
```

7. Adding build command shortcuts on my `package.json` :

---

```
"scripts": {
  "prebuild-server": "ng build --prod --aot --app server && ngc -p src/app-universal/tsconfig.server.json",
  "build-server": "ts-node src/server.ts",
  ...
},
```

and running `npm run build-server` to compile your *simplified* app and render it with universal.

8. Using Apache `Location` and `ReverseProxy` on my server to launch my main app on the `/` path, and my simplified app on `/content` or `/blog` or `/whatever` path :

---

In the /etc/apache2/site-availables/your-project.conf file (on the `<VirtualHost:.80>` block, after `DocumentRoot` for example):

```
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyVia Full
  <Proxy *>
    Require all granted
  </Proxy>
  <Location /content>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:4000
    ProxyPassReverse http://1127.0.0.1:4000
  </Location>
```

And then you can use `pm2` to keep your Node.js application up in the background: *[How To Set Up a Node.js Application for Production on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04)*

And that waq done. I had split my project into two sub-project independent from each-other and run them on the same domain, with all the `/content/*` url SEO friendly

To help you pass trough current universal errors : [Angular with universal does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131138/angular-with-universal-does-not-work/47131420?noredirect=1#comment81250811_47131420)

Comment: This seems to be a solution! Thanks for all the details!

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays there is one command which will make life a lot easier for you:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject <project-name>
```

You can read more about it here:

https://angular.io/guide/universal